# How to make an irregularly scaled x-Axis and plot to both sides of it using Highcharts/Highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to make a graph with Highcharts/Highstock which looks like this (sorry for the bad graphic ;)):

[image]

I already found out how to do the columns and the line. What I could not find out (or what might not be possible) is:

- how to have columns and lines on both sides of the x-axis?
  **edit**: I want to set the distance between the tick points manually and statically!
- how to have a x-axis which is not only irrgular, but also only shows some points with a description?

EDIT: Here is what I came up with by now: http://jsfiddle.net/pJEER/ The only thing missing is to give the columns an individual width (isn't their anything like `x: 2-4`), and to color them dynamically based on their value!

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tickPositioner 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner and ordinal as false: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock

Comment: Okay. Here is what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/pJEER/ Is it somehow possible to give the bars horizontal ranges?

Comment: You can use plotBands http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands (based on image with your concept, and info above)

Comment: but I cannot set the height of the the plotBand, can I?

Comment: Indeed, so you can use Renderer http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.rect()

Answer (score 0):

No a straight answer but some advices:

- to make column with specific width you need to have each column in a different series
- for each column you can set specific color using `data: [{ x: X, y:Y, color: specific_color}]`. So to set specific color based on value, preprocess your data with adding property `color`.

Answer (score 0):

To format a column based on their value you can use a little helper function where you return the point object with a certain color based on the input value.

```
function scatterDot(x, y, color){
  return {
    "x": x
  , "y": y
  , "color": color
  , "marker": { "fillColor": color, "states": { "hover": { "fillColor": color } } }
  };
}
```

For the dynamic plotbands you could also use a formatter function to show it depending on if it's in a specific range, making the tickpositions flexible instead of preset. I did similar for setting the datalabels.

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  formatter: function() {
    if (this.percentage >= 0) {
      return this.key +"<br />"+ this.y+" ("+Math.round(this.percentage)+"%)";
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
}
```